# Server 2012 DNS Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I am trying to set up Server 2012 on VM Workstation 10.  I am using Bridged connections and have given my server a static IP of 192.168.0.20 and my external router is at 192.168.0.1.  I have set the DNS server to point to the server: 192.168.0.20.  I have created a scope of .76 to .90 for my client PCs.  When I have installed AD DS, DHCP and DNS, and click on DNS in Server Manager, I see the following message, below.  From then on, I cannot connect my W7 virtual client PCs.  When I try to connect my W7 PCs to the server domain, I get a message saying the domain 'ept.co.uk' cannot be accessed by AD DS.  How do I resolve this issue.  I have tried this in VirtualBox but to no avail.  I am an IT trainer but not a ‘techie’ but can follow instruction and have a grasp of basic networking.  I have been at this for five days...

Error message:

'The dns server is waiting for active directory domain services (ad ds) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed. the dns server service cannot start until the initial synchronization is complete because critical dns data might not yet be replicated into this domain controller. if events in the ad ds event log indicate that there is a problem with dns name resolution, consider adding the ip address of another dns server for this domain to the dns server list in the internet protocol properties of this computer. this event will be logged every two minutes until ad ds has signaled that the initial synchronization has successfully completed.'

Any help out there?? Cheers.

Doug Fisher

Comment: When you only have 1 DC, you will always see that error message because you have a catch-22 at boot-up, of AD DS waiting for DNS, and DNS waiting for AD DS. But they will both eventually start. So I think you can safely disregard that message as far as troubleshooting this problem is concerned. Are you handing out the IP of your DNS server to your clients via DHCP? Are the clients using the DC for DNS? Sounds like your clients cannot resolve your domain via DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I would fist try nslookup command on the server and a client machine and see what it displays. Also running Dcdiag may give you some more clues. Also one big place to check will be to see if you have reverse lookup zone setup properly. And if there are other DNS logs for more clues